# 2D Circle-Circle Collision Strange Behavior

Tags: matlab, logic, 2d, collision-detection, physics

Hello StackOverflow community! I'm working in a problem with circles collision. To put it in simple terms, all collisions are ideal elastic. The balls can only move in diagonals. So this sounds pretty simple. Now, for some reason with my current code, which I'll attach below, the balls "stick" to each other instead of colliding. I think what's happening is they are constantly "swapping their velocities" and that's why they can't get apart, but I might be wrong.

[code removed]

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Comment: @kennytm almost the same syntax, but I have no idea why it put it as the first tag... I'll remove it I guess.

Comment: Simply swapping the velocities will result in unphysical movement unless you are working in a centre of momentum reference frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add another `if`condition after `if dist <= (2 * radius)` to check if they are moving towards each other or away from each other by predicting the distance between them after the next move and comparing with the current distance.

```
dist_next = sqrt( ((x(i)+velocity_x(i)) - (x(j)+velocity_x(j))^2 + ((y(i)+velocity_y(i)) - (y(j)+velocity_y(j)))^2 );

if dist_next < dist
...
end
```

I hope I got all the parenthesis right...

Comment: I kind of get the idea, but how would I implement it? If you don't mind to write an example of course :)

Comment: Nope you didn't get the parentheses right hahah, but yes, it works, they still overlap a bit, but I can fix that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Jefinthejam's answer (and I think a more widely used way to do it) would be to compute the dot product between the two velocity vectors and check its sign.

If it's negative, then the objects are going away from each other and you can safely not respond to the collision. 
The good thing is, if you need to perform the test many times per frame, computing this dot product is less expensive than the square root.